# How to grab incoming Host from HttpContext.Current

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to figure out how to grab the www.somedomain.com or even just the "someDomain" from the incoming HttpContext.Current request.  I'm going to grab it in the global.asax Application_BeginRequest

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```